# WordPress & Woocommerce variation Price

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using Woocommerce in WordPress and noticed the variation price does not show on the product page, but does when I add the item to a cart. The variation prices are the same no matter what the size selection is. I read this is an issue with Woocommerce, but I'm wondering if anyone has found a way to get the price to show. Currently as a work around, I had to add price in the product Description. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm also not all that familiar with WordPress and Woocommerce, but I have resources that can help me if the respond is above my understanding. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with standard troubleshooting protocol - check if the problem still appears with some standard theme (e.g. Storefront or TwentySeventeen) and all extra plugins disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you are wanting the chosen variation price to replace the variable price range shown, even though in your case they are all the same price. I have been able to do this in my own Woocommerce store by adding this to functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'move_single_product_variable_price_location', 2 );

function move_single_product_variable_price_location() {
    global $product;

    // Variable product only
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ):

    // removing the price of variable products
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

    // Add back the relocated (customized) price of variable products
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_variable_prices', 10 );

    endif;
}


function custom_single_product_variable_prices(){
    global $product;

    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
    }

    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price,
        div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
        div.hidden-variable-price {
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            line-height: 0px !important;
            font-size: 0% !important;
            visibility: hidden !important; 
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // When variable price is selected by default
            setTimeout( function(){
                if( 0 < $('input.variation_id').val() && null != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                    if($('p.availability'))
                        $('p.availability').remove();

                    $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
                    console.log($('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html());
                }
            }, 300 );

            // On live variation selection
            $('select').blur( function(){
                if( 0 < $('input.variation_id').val() && null != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                    if($('.price p.availability') || $('.price p.stock') )
                        $('p.price p').each(function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });

                    $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
                    console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
                } else {
                    $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                    if($('p.availability'))
                        $('p.availability').remove();
                    console.log('NULL');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php

    echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
    <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';
}
```